# Java Code formatting for statment

Tags: java, for-loop, formatting

Is their a better way to format this `for-loop`?

The user enters two integers which are initialised to `x and y` the program prints these values out as + for the first number and - for the second number.

> FOR EXAMPLE 9 and 5 would result in
>
> > +++++++++-----

I tried using a nested `for-loop`, but this resulted in

> +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x,y,total = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter two numbers greater than 0 and no greater than 20!");
    x = sc.nextInt();
    y = sc.nextInt();

    draw(x,y);  

    private static void draw(int x, int y) {
    for(int i=1; i<=x; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("+");

    }
    for(int j=1; j<=y; j++)
    {
        System.out.print("-");
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's for a University assignment where the first number inputted is printed out as plusses and the second number is printed as minuses. The code so far does as i wish. I'm just looking how to improve it, because nobody's code is perfect, right!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make it smaller :)

```
private static void draw(int x, int y) {
    for (int i = -x; i < y; i++) {
        System.out.print(i<0 ? "+" : "-");
    }
}
```

Comment: Place of "+","-" is reverse :) Result for x = 5, y=4 is -----++++

Comment: What actually is `?` in Java.

Comment: @GrahamWarrender It's ternary operator `?:`

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x, y, total = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter two numbers greater than 0 and no greater than 20!");
        x = sc.nextInt();
        y = sc.nextInt();

        draw(x, y);
    }

    private static void draw(int x, int y) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
            System.out.print("+");

        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= y; j++) {
            System.out.print("-");
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
Enter two numbers greater than 0 and no greater than 20!

9   --> Hit enter.
5   --> Hit enter again!
+++++++++-----
```

Comment: Is ıt same with Graham Warrender's code in question?

Answer (score 1):

I would get rid of the loops all together, and use [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html).

```
private static void draw(int x, int y) {
    System.out.print(Stringutils.repeat("+", x));
    System.out.println(StringUtils.repeat("-", y));
}
```

Comment: You forgot to print it: `System.out.print(StringUtils.repeat("+", x) + StringUtils.repeat("y", x));`